# why am i not able to open the admin page before migration?

Tags: django, django-admin, admin

while you are creating a project and starting an app, you will run the server and get an appropriate page. and adding an /admin to the 8000 will show the admin page, but is it possible to get the admin page before migration?i tried to open the admin page by adding, /admin to the url before migrating.

Comment: As a short:
It is not possible to access the admin page before running migrations because the database schema, including the required tables, is not yet in place. Running migrations is necessary to set up the database schema and make the admin page available for use.

Answer (score 0):

Because the admin site has as main purpose, displaying, editing, creating and removing records. This thus means that if you look at a model, it shows a list of records, behind the curtains, it will thus make a database query.

If you did not migrate properly, the tables for the corresponding models are not created, or are missing columns, or the columns have the wrong type. This thus means that it is very likely that the query will fail, and thus so does the admin page rendering the records.